# CI deploy strategy

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

Suppose `Team A` is working on `library A version 1.0.1`
`Team B` is working on `library B version 2.0.3`
we want to deliver these two artifacts together.

```
library A depends on Library B
```

In this case should we configure Jenkins to deploy artifacts on maven remote repo, so that developers work always with lateste SNAPSHOT version ?
What would be the best practice here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

- If the latest released version of library B (say 2.0.2) is enough for library A, i.e. it provides all the functionality that is needed, A can depend on B in version 2.0.2. When you publish library A in version 1.0.1 together with B in 2.0.2 there will be no surprises.
- If the latest released version of library B is *not* enough, i.e. A needs new methods of B that are not yet released, you need to use SNAPSHOT builds of library B. So Team B has to build a SNAPSHOT version regularly and team A can use it. Before the release, B needs to build a release version and after that, A can build against this release version of B.

Answer (score 0):

Just deploy your SNAPSHOT versions to a common Maven repository using `mvn deploy` and declare lib B `2.0.4-SNAPSHOT` as dependency in the pom.xml of lib A.

To be sure build lib A with `mvn <goal> -U` to fire Maven to update SNAPSHOT dependencies.